# Can I take Extra Followers more than once?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

I can't seem to find information on whether you can take feats more than once. A number of feats say that you can, but I can't seem to find the general rule that says one way or another.

If I could take Extra Followers more than once, I assume that the number would go up x2 each time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The general rule is on page 89 of the PHB (or [here](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm) (scroll down to *Feat Descriptions/Benefit*)).

> If a character has the same feat more than once, its benefits do not
> stack unless indicated otherwise in the description. In general,
> having a feat twice is the same as having it once.

The feat *Extra Followers* *(Heroes of Battle, p. 97)* doesn’t say that its effects
stack if you take it multiple times. So there would be no benefit if a character gained it twice.